# ttk.OptionMenu has no outline/border

Tags: python, tkinter

I am using `ttk.Optionmenu()` in my GUI but am annoyed that when there is no mouse-over condition, the menu/button does not have any visuals showing its border. It is not giving me any element_options to see if I can change specific styling for this widget.

I would love it if there was a way for the button to look like a button all the time instead of just when it gets focus... otherwise it looks sort of blaghh.

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar(root)
opmenu = ttk.OptionMenu(root, var, 'One', 'Two', 'Three')
opmenu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I know how to change the `style` for the widgets but none address its at-rest appearance. I've tried 'googling' in hopes to find a solution but to no avail.
Using Python 3.5.2 and tkinter 8.6

Comment: It is not very clear what is the problem. Testing your code on Linux, gives the distinguishable appearance similar to a button. Are you by chance using windows?

Comment: Yes I am using windows... sorry I forgot to mention that in the question.

Comment: According to [documentation](http://infohost.nmt.edu/tcc/help/pubs/tkinter/web/ttk-Menubutton.html)

many of the typical configurable features of the tkinter OptionMenu are not available for ttk. Note that the Style name for ttk  OptionMenu is TMenubutton.

Comment: There might be a way to layer a normal ttk button on top of the menu button and use event handlers to bring the OptionMenu or the Button to the front. I think this would do the trick.

Comment: That is one way to work around it. I was looking for a more direct approach. If it is working as it should in Linux, I'm curious as to why not in windows... and yes I did find out that its 'TMenubutton' via the `winfo_class()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Update:

After some digging it looks like you can force the style to be claimed away from windows. It does not look as good however I think you may be able to set up your style to look the way you want after you have used `theme_use('clam')`

Take a look at this example:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

var1 = tk.StringVar()
var1.set("One")

s = ttk.Style(root)
s.theme_use('clam')
s.configure('raised.TMenubutton', borderwidth=1)

opmenu = ttk.OptionMenu(root, var1, "One", "One", "Two", "Three",
                        style = 'raised.TMenubutton')

opmenu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

In response to your comment on using a button with a popup menu you could do something like this:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

root = tk.Tk()

popup = tk.Menu(root, tearoff=0)
popup.add_command(label="One", command= lambda: update_btn("One"))
popup.add_command(label="Two", command= lambda: update_btn("Two"))
popup.add_command(label="Three", command= lambda: update_btn("Three"))

btn = ttk.Button(root, text="One")
btn.pack()

def update_btn(x):
    btn.config(text=x)

def btn_popup(event):
    try:
        popup.tk_popup(event.x_root, event.y_root, 0)
    finally:
        popup.grab_release()

btn.bind("<Button-1>", btn_popup)

root.mainloop()
```

Comment: Thanks for that. You example actually got me thinking. Use a regular button like in your sample code, however, instead of bringing forward the option menu button on mouse over then when you click it. It would open a contextual menu... I would love to learn how to write ttk widgets and then just go in and modify the core code to fix it.

Comment: @ErniePeters I have updated my answer as I have found out how to force the style. You will need to fully configure the style to match the aesthetic you want but it will allow you to keep the OptionMenu in the "raised" state.

Comment: @ErniePeters however it looks to be a lot of work so I think your idea of using a button and then providing a pop up menu should work better.

Comment: Thanks. Your example to force the style is actually telling me that it is a problem with a specific style because the 'clam', 'classic', etc all have that 'raised' look but the main windows theme one. I am going to be looking into this a bit more and maybe find the problem in the ttk core files... I was playing with the styles earlier too but didn't connect the dots until just now.

Comment: when and if I find a solution I will post it to satisfy anyones curriousity

Comment: @ErniePeters Check out the update on my answer. From your comment on using a button with a pop up menu I think it will work well for your needs.

Comment: That's neat. I don't think anybody would suspect it not being and option menu if they didn't see the code besides the down arrow that it provides. That is easily taken care of with a down arrow image on the button. Nice work thanks. I'll make that the answer for now. If I find out why the optionmenu doesn't work with the default windows theme I will post it here as a complimentary addition to your answer. Cheers!

Comment: @ErniePeters Glad to help :). As for the optionmenu "Not working" I think its because tkinter is getting its style directly from windows. This is something I have had to deal with in the past with scrollbars.

Comment: Thanks for the heads up. I will be using scrollbars in the very near future

Answer (score 0):

I found a solution for permanently showing the border of the vista style:

```
import tkinter as tk
from tkinter import ttk

# Always show the active style
def alwaysActiveStyle(widget):
    widget.config(state="active")
    widget.bind("<Leave>", lambda e: "break")

root = tk.Tk()

var = tk.StringVar(root)
opmenu = ttk.OptionMenu(root, var, 'One', 'Two', 'Three')
alwaysActiveStyle(opmenu)
opmenu.pack()

root.mainloop()
```

I hope that it solves some problems.